# Looking to set a fixed tab for a specific selenium python script in vsc

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking to run 3 scripts in a selenium browser.

I'd like each of them to run in their specific tab, or assign one tab only for one script

I tried

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3])
```

but it always changes the tab for that script everytime I launch it

Thank you for the help

Comment: Is it okay with you if you launch 3 instance of chrome and then do stuff ?

Comment: thank you for the reply. If I could, I would prefer to do it with one instance and in this case I can't really use 3 instances of chrome, I kinda need them all within one instance and at least different tabs so no interference

Comment: I am not sure about that part, but if you are open for "Complete or do task in first tab then move to 2nd tab and complete or do some stuff over there and the either move to first tab or third tab to do stuff" - let me know, I can help.

Comment: thank you. I will do more research on this whether it is doable. I will let you know if I need  anything. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you are in single threaded environment, I don't think that single thread can operate on 3 different tabs at once.